# How to get cookies with Java?

Tags: java, cookies

How can I get a cookie from a web page using Java? I mean only Java not with Servlets or etc..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use [`java.net.URLConnection`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) for this. It offers a [`getHeaderFields()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getHeaderFields%28%29) method to get the response headers. The cookies are set by `Set-Cookie` header.

```
URLConnection connection = new URL("http://google.com").openConnection();
List<String> cookies = connection.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie");
// ...
```

Answer (score 3):

You can either [get the cookies from the header](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/deployment/deployment-guide/cookie_support.html),

or you can use [Apache commons](http://commons.apache.org/) and [use their functionality](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Apache-Common/GetCookievalueandsetcookievalue.htm).