# Java get Session Cookies

Tags: java, session, cookies, session-cookies

[Getting header fields from a URLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921056/how-to-get-cookies-with-java) doesn't get session cookies for me.

When I use `CookieManager` I can get session cookies from a URL:

```
CookieManager manager = new CookieManager();
manager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
CookieHandler.setDefault(manager);

URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
con.getContent();

CookieStore cookieJar = manager.getCookieStore();
List<HttpCookie> cookies = cookieJar.getCookies();
```

This is fine, but I need to send a POST request. So I am writing to the URLConnection's output stream. My question is how to get the session cookies after sending the POST request.

Comment: Am I missing something ? Have you tried `Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();`?

Comment: @ringbearer What is `request`?

Comment: Ok I thought you were using Java Servlet API.

Comment: what you are using SErvlet,Spring,Rest or any other ?

Comment: @yogeshprajapati No libraries/frameworks, just standard Java SE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the same CookieManager object with your first and subsequent requests using URLConnection.